# BackboneJS Routing

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

My app's index page is at `http://cms/admin` (I'm on localhost). On the index page there is only one `a` element:

```
<a href="/admin/test">deneme</a>
```

When i click on the link it goes to `/cms/admin/test`

I want to use BackboneJS's routing mechanism to convert my app to ajax friendly app but i can't do it until now. Here is my JS code:

```
$(function() {
    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            "test": "defaultRoute"
        },

        defaultRoute: function() {
            console.log('its here');
        }
    });

    var appRouter = new AppRouter();

    Backbone.history.start({
        pushState: true,
        slient: true,
        root: '/admin/'
    });
});
```

When i run the page and click the link, it doesn't log anything to console and browser follows the link. After page loads, it logs "its here" message.

I already tried it without the root param, "/admin/test" instead of "test". i tried every combination of: "test", "/test", "test/", "/admin/test", "admin/test" etc..

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to override the default behavior of the link.

You have to move between pages explicitly calling `appRouter.navigate("test", {trigger: true});`. So try to capture the *click event* over your link within a [View.events](http://backbonejs.org/#View-delegateEvents), [prevent the default behavior of the link](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and call [appRouter.navigate()](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-navigate)

#### Update

Also you can do it this in a batch:

```
$("a.bb_link").each( function( index, link ){
  $(link).click( function( event ){
    event.preventDefault();
    appRouter.navigate( $(this).attr( "href" ), {trigger: true} );
  });
});​
```

Every link with class `bb_link` will be using the Backbone.Router.

Comment: There's also a good example of this in Tim Branyen's backbone-boilerplate using a `data-bypass` attribute: https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone-boilerplate/blob/master/app/main.js#L22

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your anchor tag as follows:

`<a href="#admin/test">deneme</a>`

Note the hash (#)